# PN532 + libnfc + linux

Tags: linux, rfid

Hi i bought a [PN532 breakout board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/364), I did install my cable FTDI, i did install NFC, nfc-list recognized my PN532, i did start the nfc-poll, its in listening mode, i've got my mifare card tag that came together and I did try to read, but it didn't read. So where could be the problem? I did solder the pin-heads to the FTDI cable, I connected it to my USB (linux ubuntu 10.04), i downloaded the last stable libnfc, compiled with the options ./configure --with-drivers=pn532_uart --enable-serial-autoprobe, as i wrote, the nfc-list recognized but now i cannot read a card with nfc-pool (but nfc-pool recognized as well my reader, it is in listening).Anything else to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer:

PN532 + UART just works with libnfc unstable (1.5.x).

Answer (score 1):

Was the card a mifare card?
We have build pn532 breakout and we can use nfc-list, nfc-poll and other tools in examples directory.

here is the result:
http://www.xfpga.com/P_view.asp?pid=379